# How to upload photo to flickr using RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, file-upload, flickr

I use Flickraw in my test app

Follow the [example](https://github.com/hanklords/flickraw/blob/master/examples/upload.rb),

I can upload file by Keying file path , but I want to use form_tag helper

This is my view

```
= form_tag :upload_photo_to_Flickr , :multipart => true do 
= hidden_field_tag :token, @upload_info[:token] 
= label_tag "PHOTO" 
= file_field_tag :photo 
= submit_tag "Upload Photo"
```

Controller is

```
 def upload_photo_to_Flickr
    file_path = params[:photo]
    flickr.upload_photo file_path , :title => "please" , :description=>"successfully"
 end
```

It show error message **ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0))**

And I also try the other method using read ,

```
 def upload_photo_to_Flickr
    file_path = params[:photo].read
    flickr.upload_photo file_path , :title => "please" , :description=>"successfully"
 end
```

It show error message **ArgumentError (string contains null byte)**

The params is

```
{"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x10ba37648 
  @original_filename="test.jpg",
  @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/wy/5yx_py3s02g8l0kw0frrpg_m0000gn/T/RackMultipart20111110-   
   1832-18ufrmm-0>,
  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; 
  filename=\"test.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
  @content_type="image/jpeg">,

   "commit"=>"Upload Photo \350\201\236",
   "token"=>"XXXX",
   "authenticity_token"=>"o9PhVeE6u1MGfol/PvGQkLE8RCL5tJat+1AQlygGOKc=",
   "utf8"=>"\342\234\223"
}
```

**How  to get file path ?**

Because It can work like this

```
def upload_photo_to_Flickr
  file_path = "/Desktop/test.jpg"
  flickr.upload_photo file_path , :title => "please" , :description=>"successfully"
end
```

**Or I have to try another method to get file path instead of form_tag ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a solution!

In controller , using

> flickr.upload_photo(params[:photo].tempfile.path)